# Using microphone input to create a music visualization in real time on a 3D globe

Tags: linux, audio, fft, visualization, raspberry-pi3

I am involved in a side project that has a loop of LEDs around 1.5m in diameter with a rotor on the bottom which spins the loop. A raspberry pi controls the LEDs so that they create what appears to be a 3D globe of light. I am interested in a project that takes a microphone input and turns it into a column of pixels which is rendered on the loop in real time. The goal of this is to see if we can have it react to music in real-time. So far I've come up with this idea:

Using a FFT to quickly turn the input sound into a function that maps to certain pixels to certain colors based on the amplitude of the resultant function at frequencies, so the equator of the globe would respond to the strength of the lower-frequency sound, progressing upwards towards the poles which would respond to high frequency sound.

I can think of a few potential problems, including:

- Performance on a raspberry pi. If the response lags too far behind the music it wouldn't seem to the observer to be responding to the specific song he/she is also hearing.
- Without detecting the beat or some overall characteristic of the music that people understand it might be difficult for the observers to understand the output is correlated to the music.
- The rotor has different speeds, so the image is only stationary if the rate of spin is matched perfectly to the refresh rate of the LEDs. This is a problem, but also possibly helpful because I might be able to turn down both the refresh rate and the rotor speed to reduce the computational load on the raspberry pi.

With that backstory, I should probably now ask a question. In general, how would you go about doing this? I have some experience with parallel computing and numerical methods but I am totally ignorant of music and tone and what-not. Part of my problem is I know the raspberry pi is the newest model, but I am not sure what its parallel capabilities are. I need to find a few linux friendly tools or libraries that can do an FFT on an ARM processor, and be able to do the post-processing in real time. I think a delay of ~0.25s or about would be acceptable. I feel like I'm in over my head so I thought id ask you guys for input. 
Thanks!